# Joomla Editor in 1.5 not displaying in articles or modules

Tags: joomla, editor

Some time ago I cleaned the Joomla database of some eroneous items and I fear that in the process an element related to the loading of the Joomla Editor may have been removed. Currently, when attempting to edit an article or module, I am only shown the article description drop downs, name fields etc but no editor. I no longer have access to any local backups of the darn thing so - I am lost.

Comment: which table did you delete items from ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a few things:
A) What did you delete?  Do you remember specifically?  If it was the default editor - if you were so inclined you could create a 'fresh install' and export the specific tables you may have deleted and import them into the current joomla site.

B) Are you sure that the editor is not selected as 'none' under global settings?  You can globally turn off the editor under global settings - check that first.

Just some additional questions; when you say no editor - do you see the pure HTML output?  Or is there nothing there to edit?

If nothing else I hope my suggestions above give you some ideas to track down and point you in the right direction.  I'd love to see it be something as simple as going to global settings and enabling the editor ;)

Also, if you did in fact delete the stock/default joomla editor - there is a great (and amazingly powerful) [extension called JCE](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/88) - which is an editor that can be downloaded/installed.  For 1.5 - it adds some cool functionality and is very customizable.  Just a thought if you can't find anything else that would work.

Good luck!